# insert into package using java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I've a package in Oracle 11g database to insert records as shown below:

Users table has user_id, prod-id, email, locale, created dt & modified date

```
exec demo.USERS_PKG.INSERT_USERS(null,1,'abc@abc.com','us',sysdate,sysdate)
```

I'm new to Java. Can any one provide me sample Java program to insert records using above package?

Note: I don't want hibernate, just plain jdbc calls but not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Search in google: jdbc oracle invoke stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to qualify stored-proc name when you call it.

```
  CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call demo.USERS_PKG.INSERT_USERS(?, ?, ?,?,?,?)}");
```

In order to work with oracle database, you have to download [JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) and take a look at [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/dbmgmnt.htm#CHDEJECF) (sample).

Comment: Can u provide complete sample including db connection?

Comment: @Mike - don't be lazy.  Read the tutorials in Jugal Shah's answer.